# Access is denied. Check credentials and try again - occurs occasionally

Tags: exchangewebservices

I've created Outlook Addin and I have an issue with email handling in C# by Exchange Api 2.2. Form time to time I get such error from users "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again" when trying to execute this code (use are mailbox owners and have full rights):

```
var selection = Adapter.Instance.OutlookApplicationRef.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
string entryId = selection[1].EntryID;

EWS.AlternateId objAltID = new EWS.AlternateId();
objAltID.Format = EWS.IdFormat.HexEntryId;
objAltID.Mailbox = "myemail@test.test";
objAltID.UniqueId = entryId;

//Convert  PR_ENTRYID identifier format to an EWS identifier. 
EWS.AlternateIdBase objAltIDBase = esb.ConvertId(objAltID, EWS.IdFormat.EwsId);
EWS.AlternateId objAltIDResp = (EWS.AlternateId)objAltIDBase;
string ewsId = objAltIDResp.UniqueId;

var psToLoad = new EWS.PropertySet(EWS.BasePropertySet.IdOnly, EWS.EmailMessageSchema.InternetMessageId, EWS.EmailMessageSchema.Sender,
                                EWS.EmailMessageSchema.ToRecipients, EWS.EmailMessageSchema.CcRecipients, EWS.ItemSchema.Body,
                                EWS.EmailMessageSchema.MimeContent);

var EWSEmailMessage = EWS.EmailMessage.Bind(service, ewsId, psToLoad);
```

I get this error on "EmailMessage.Bind" from time to time only. For 99 % of users it works. I have something about 5000 of users. We compared configuration in Exchange and everything is the same like with users where application works correctly. Maybe there is a better way to get email information using selected email in Outlook (2010).

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this error and what we found was it was a faulty calendar permission on one of the permissions on the mailbox you are trying to access.

Hope this helps